# Using a SQL inner join for string matching?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm trying to use an inner join to do a string match for me.
I have an Organisation table with a RegNo column on which I want to match
There are 3 Organisations with the same RegNo (8888) 
Using the script below I get the following results

```
Row#     KeyA     KeyB
----     ----     ----
1        5        1
2        7        1
3        1        5
4        7        5
5        1        7
6        5        7
```

In my scenario Row #1 (KeyA=5, KeyB=1) and Row #3 (KeyA=1, KeyB=5) are the "same"
 
And  #2 and #5 are the same 
As well as #4 and #6

Is there as way to remove these "duplicates" from the result?

Here's the script to create table and data

```
USE YourTempDB
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Organisation]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Organisation]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Organisation](
    [ENT_Key] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [RegNo] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [TaxNo] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [TradeAs] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Organisation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ENT_Key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Organisation] ([ENT_Key], [Name], [RegNo], [TaxNo], [TradeAs]) VALUES (1, N'ASD', N'8888', N'ASD', N'ASD')
INSERT [dbo].[Organisation] ([ENT_Key], [Name], [RegNo], [TaxNo], [TradeAs]) VALUES (2, N'ZAQ', N'ZAQ', N'ZAQ', N'ZAQ')
INSERT [dbo].[Organisation] ([ENT_Key], [Name], [RegNo], [TaxNo], [TradeAs]) VALUES (3, N'QWE', N'4321', N'4321', N'QWE')
INSERT [dbo].[Organisation] ([ENT_Key], [Name], [RegNo], [TaxNo], [TradeAs]) VALUES (4, N'SDF', N'1234', N'1234', N'SDF')
INSERT [dbo].[Organisation] ([ENT_Key], [Name], [RegNo], [TaxNo], [TradeAs]) VALUES (5, N'ZXC', N'8888', N'ZXC', N'ZXC')
INSERT [dbo].[Organisation] ([ENT_Key], [Name], [RegNo], [TaxNo], [TradeAs]) VALUES (6, N'WSX', N'9999', N'9999', N'WSX')
INSERT [dbo].[Organisation] ([ENT_Key], [Name], [RegNo], [TaxNo], [TradeAs]) VALUES (7, N'POI', N'8888', N'8888', N'POI')
INSERT [dbo].[Organisation] ([ENT_Key], [Name], [RegNo], [TaxNo], [TradeAs]) VALUES (8, N'ASD', N'Monquestilin Holdings ', N'Monquestilin Holdings ', N'ASD')
INSERT [dbo].[Organisation] ([ENT_Key], [Name], [RegNo], [TaxNo], [TradeAs]) VALUES (9, N'Trupickefazz Direct ', N'Trupickefazz Direct ', N'Trupickefazz Direct ', N'Trupickefazz Direct ')
INSERT [dbo].[Organisation] ([ENT_Key], [Name], [RegNo], [TaxNo], [TradeAs]) VALUES (10, N'Rapnipedower  ', N'Rapnipedower  ', N'Rapnipedower  ', N'Rapnipedower  ')
/****** Object:  Default [DF_Organisation_VendorRegDate]    Script Date: 07/01/2014 09:24:13 ******/

SELECT [t0].[ENT_Key] AS [KeyA], [t1].[ENT_Key] AS [KeyB]
FROM [Organisation] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Organisation] AS [t1] ON [t0].[RegNo] = [t1].[RegNo]                       
WHERE [t0].[ENT_Key] != [t1].[ENT_Key]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `where` condition to be:

```
WHERE [t0].[ENT_Key] < [t1].[ENT_Key]
```

Insend of `!=`